# Regex for telephone numbers

Tags: regex, preg-match

I'm trying to do a regex for telephone numbers. I'm using named captures, so hopefully my regex will be a bit more understandable.

```
^(?<country_code>1|808)?(?<area_code>\d{3})?(?<local_number>\d{7})$
```

Assume the following:

- all area codes are 3 digits
- all local numbers are 7 digits
- there are only 2 country codes: 1 and 808

Tests:

- `12025551212` <-- 1 202 5551212
- `2025551212` <-- 202 5551212
- `8082025551212` <-- 808 202 5551212
- `8085551212` <-- problem here

The problem with the last test is that the regex thinks the `808` is a country code. Although it is, in this string, the `808` represents the area code. How should I modify my regex so that the 808 is interpreted as an area code instead of a country code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given these constraints, you could adjust the regex to require the country code to be paired with an area code. I've highlighted the changed bits:

```
^(?:(?<country_code>1|808)?(?<area_code>\d{3}))?(?<local_number>\d{7})$
 ^^^                                          ^^
```

There's now a non-capturing group around the country code and area code, and the area code group is required if that group is present at all.

That being said, the approach you're taking isn't going to work on a more general basis. Three-digit area codes and seven-digit local numbers are not used in all countries — in fact, not all countries even **use** area codes. (For instance, phone numbers in Greenland are six digits long with no area code, as the country only has around 56,000 inhabitants.)

Comment: I'll explore the non-capturing groups approach. I was not having much success with it. I understand this won't work for all phone numbers in the world, but it'll work for what I need.

Comment: It won't work for any phone numbers outside the US and Canada (NANP), other than by chance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest direct answer to your question is probably:

```
^(?<country_code>1|808)??(?<area_code>\d{3})?(?<local_number>\d{7})$
```

Making the country code match 0-1 times *Reluctantly*.

However, @Duskwuff's answer is better, as it requires an area code to be present for a country code to be matched, which I assume to be more correct.

Comment: I dunno - I really like this answer.  It's hella clever.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Thanks!  However, this would accept "12223333" with a country code "1" and local_number "2223333", but no area code, which I doubt would be the desired behavior.

Comment: Hm.  I didn't think about that.  Still clever as hell, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?<country_code>1|808)?(?<area_code>\d{3}))?(?<local_number>\d{7})$
```

Comment: That would end up recognizing 8088088088088088088088085551212 as a valid phone number, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: Though I think you were on to something REALLY clever here: `(?<country_code>1|808)??(?<area_code>\d{3})?(?<local_number>\d{7})`  By using a 0 or 1 operator here and making it lazy, it tries to match without a country code first, generating a desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead like this:

```
^(?<country_code>1|808(?=\d{10}))?(?<area_code>\d{3})?(?<local_number>\d{7})$
```

This will make sure that there are always 10 digits after country code.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/SnPE3eyB3E

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that If your number has a Country Code, it Must Sport an area Code, too. Thus it must be of length 13 which is Not Reflected in your regex.

Change it into the following:

```
^((?<country_code>1|808)(?<area_code>\d{3})|(?<area_code>\d{3})?)(?<local_number>\d{7})$
```

The First Alternative has lengths 4 or 6, the Second 0 or 3. since you Match the complete Input, at most One Alternative can Match any Input.